# Referencing extended manytomany User model in Django...?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm having a few issues referencing an extended user model (UserProfile) within a template.

What I have setup is the currently logged in user will be the "User object" associated to that comment. I have done this as follows:

admin.py:

```
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('created_by', 'post', 'created', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created')
    search_fields = ('created_by', 'body')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        if not hasattr(instance,'created_by'):
            instance.created_by = request.user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):

        def set_user(instance):
            if not instance.created_by:
                instance.created_by = request.user
            instance.save()

        if formset.model == Comment:
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            map(set_user, instances)
            formset.save_m2m()
            return instances
        else:
            return formset.save()
```

My Comment model is as follows:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='created_by', null=True, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
         return "Comment by {} on {}".format(self.created_by, self.post)
```

My UserProfile model extends the User model as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    user_avatar = models.ImageField(storage=site_media_upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
```

Everything works. I can save comments and associate all comments to the logged in user instance. The issue I now have is this: I want to display the user_avatar (as defined in the UserProfile model) for the user associated with each comment (not to the currently logged in user).

So far I have tried the following:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ comment.created_by.user.userprofile.user_avatar.url }}">

<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ comment.created_by.userprofile.user_avatar.url }}">
```

But nothing seems to work (the last guess was more a smack of desperation than an actually realistic possibility).

So, from the above models - and the knowledge that the comment is created with an instance of the currently logged User object - how do I get this all working?

My only other thought is that I might need to add in something like this to the comments model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    commenter_avatar = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile.user_avatar, related_name='user_avatar', null=True, blank=True)
```

And perhaps I could perhaps request user.userprofile.user_avatar in the comments admin save() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url` property of an image field already adds the `MEDIA_URL`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

So the final tag should be :

```
<img src="{{ comment.created_by.userprofile.user_avatar.url }}">
```

Provided the user profile actually has an image

Comment: Awesome - this worked! I am unsure as to why this works - when I save the comment I use the User instance. So surely I need to say "find the comment, find who it was created_by (which is a User)...so go into that user and find their userprofile then find their user_avatar.url...unless the created_by and user and sort of inter-relational (are they one of the same?)

Comment: You reference the User object in created_by, each User object has a foreign key to UserProfile through the userprofile related attribute. Then in the template the ORM just follow the reference to the User, then the UserProfile, then the image

Comment: So user and created_by are one of the same (OneToOneField) and then we can hop from either to UserProfile. Kind of makes sense. Is it best do you think to override the default Django User model? I read some say yes, some say no...as in, the whole point of Django is not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you have started your project a while ago, don't bother migrating to another user model. In other case, I've been using AUTH_USER_MODEL override for a while and it make things clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    user_avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/") // no need null=True, blank=True

class Comment(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='created_by', null=True, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
         return "Comment by {} on {}".format(self.created_by, self.post)


<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ comment.created_by.user_avatar.url }}">
```

I think you use too much USER relation simplify your code.
Try it !!

Comment: Yes - this is quite pure to link the Comments model to the "extended User"  UserProfile model - however, further down the code I will need to extend to the User model anwyay - e.g., `Comment by {{ comment.created_by.user.username }} on {{ comment.created }}`